# VBA code executes in break mode but skips to the end during normal run

Tags: vba, excel

This code works perfectly if I run it in break mode by stepping through each line. However, if I run it normally, it seems like it just skips to the end. It gives me a message box of a one second run time and none of the lines of code have been executed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub addVals()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, sheetName As String, timer As Double
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
timer = Now()
For i = 1 To 7
    sheetName = Range("sheetnames2").Offset(i, 0).Value
    For j = 1 To 3000
        If Sheets(sheetName).Range("P" & j).Value <> 0 Then
            For Each Cell In Range("R" & j, "R" & j + 30)
                If Cell = 1 Then Range("S" & j).Value = Cell.Offset(0, -17).Value: Exit For
            Next Cell
        Else
        End If
    Next j
Next i
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
MsgBox (Format(Now() - timer, "HH:MM:SS"))
End Sub
```

Comment: How do you know the code has not executed?  What if you add a test line like `Range("A1")="test"` right before the `For` loop begins...  I suspect it will execute. If so, move it into the loop.

Comment: Also you **should not be using the keyword `Cell`** this way. It is a reserved word, and the `For Each..Next` loop requires a variable in that position.  Help avoid problems like this by making the first line of the module [always] `Option Explicit`, which will force you to properly declared your variables.

Comment: One problem is...If `sheetnames2` is a variable then you need to assign it to a range and remove the `""` inside the parenthesis.

Comment: Also, you're using depending on the value of `Sheetnames` you may be using `Offset` incorrectly.

Comment: Make sure to qualify *all* your Range() calls with a sheet name - not doing this is a common source of issues.  Also note your `Exit For` probably isn't working the way you expect...

Comment: I wonder what is `Range("sheetnames2")`? Is it one cell or several cells? If it contains several cells, then with `Offset` you just move this range down. The `Value` property will return array in this case.

Comment: I know that the Macro Works when stepping through because it returns the values that I am looking to retrieve. However, when running the macro runs and nothing seems to execute. "Sheetnames2" is a named range which is a sing cell not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of corrections:

```
Sub addVals()

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, sheetName As String, timer As Double
    Dim sht As Worksheet, Cell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    timer = Now()

    For i = 1 To 7
        sheetName = Range("sheetnames2").Offset(i, 0).Value
        With Sheets(sheetName) '<< scope the loop to the correct sheet
            For j = 1 To 3000
                If .Range("P" & j).Value <> 0 Then
                    For Each Cell In .Range("R" & j).Resize(30, 1).Cells
                        If Cell.Value = 1 Then
                            .Range("S" & j).Value = Cell.Offset(0, -17).Value
                            Exit For '<< unless you really meant what you wrote?
                        End If
                    Next Cell
                End If
            Next j
        End With
    Next i

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    MsgBox (Format(Now() - timer, "HH:MM:SS"))
End Sub
```

Note this one-liner:

```
If Cell = 1 Then Range("S" & j).Value = Cell.Offset(0, -17).Value: Exit For
```

is functionally the same as:

```
If Cell = 1 Then 
    Range("S" & j).Value = Cell.Offset(0, -17).Value
End If
Exit For
```

and is *not* the same as:

```
If Cell = 1 Then 
    Range("S" & j).Value = Cell.Offset(0, -17).Value
    Exit For
End If
```

...so it might not be behaving as you expect

Comment: You mean that my one liner is equivalent to:
          If Cell = 1 Then 
          Range("S" & j).Value = Cell.Offset(0, -17).Value
          Exit For
          End If
NO?

Comment: No - that was my point in making that point!  `:` just lets you write two different "lines" of code on one line - it doesn't "join" that second line to your `Then` statement. A one-liner `If...Then` can only have one `Then` statement, so if you want to execute multiple statements then use the multi-line `If...End If` version.  Edited my answer for clarity on that part.